# How to use a column from joined table in a join with a subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MainTable m
INNER JOIN JoinedTable j on j.ForeignID = m.ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM SubQueryTable sq
            WHERE sq.ForeignID = j.ID
            ORDER BY VersionColumn DESC)
```

So basically, from SubQueryTable, I only want to retrieve a single row which has the maximum value for VersionColumn for all rows with a certain ID that I can get from JoinedTable.

T-SQL doesn't let me do this, what's a good way to solve this problem?

What I'm trying to prevent is loading the entire SubQueryTable and doing the filtering when it's too late as in....

```
SELECT *
FROM MainTable m
INNER JOIN JoinedTable j on j.ForeignID = m.ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM SubQueryTable sq
            ORDER BY VersionColumn DESC) sj ON sj.ForeignID = j.ID
```

I fear this second version performs the very slow subquery first and only filters it when it has loaded all the rows, but I want to filter sooner.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will perform well if you have index on VersionColumn

```
SELECT *
FROM MainTable m
INNER JOIN JoinedTable j on j.ForeignID = m.ID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM SubQueryTable sq
            WHERE  sq.ForeignID = j.ID
            ORDER BY VersionColumn DESC) sj
```

Comment: I had never heard of CROSS APPLY until now (no SQL wizard here, but I come across it every so often) and it was exactly what I needed!

Comment: It is used mainly for table valued functions but as you can see it has its uses. For more: http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained

Comment: @MikeCheel I am sorry, but those examples are terrible, he could have done the same with a simple aggregate and a join. This asked question is a much better example on the use of cross apply. Another good example of cross join would have been a calculation used several times

Answer (score 0):

**Answer** :

Hi,

Below query I have created as per your requirement using Country, State and City tables.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM (
> SELECT  m.countryName, j.StateName,c.CityName , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.stateid ORDER BY c.cityid desc) AS 'x'
> FROM CountryMaster m
> INNER JOIN StateMaster j on j.CountryID = m.CountryID
> INNER JOIN dbo.CityMaster c ON j.StateID = c.StateID 
> ) AS numbered WHERE x = 1
> ```

**Below is your solution and above is only for your reference.**

> ```
> SELECT * FROM (
> SELECT  m.MainTablecolumnNm, j.JoinedTablecolumnNm,c.SubQueryTableColumnName , ROW_NUMBER()
> OVER(PARTITION BY sj.ForeignID ORDER BY c.sjID desc) AS 'abc'
> FROM MainTable m
> INNER JOIN JoinedTable j on j.ForeignID = m.ID
> INNER JOIN SubQueryTable sj ON sj.ForeignID = j.ID 
> ) AS numbered WHERE abc = 1
> ```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**